# UPDATE … FROM syntax with sub-query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table, `items`, with a `priority` column, which is just an integer.  In trying to do some bulk operations, I'm trying to reset the `priority` to be a sequential number.

I've been able to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to successfully generate a table that has the new `priority` values I want.  Now, I just need to get the values from that `SELECT` query into the matching records in the actual `items` table.

I've tried something like this:

```
UPDATE
  "items"
SET
  "priority" = tempTable.newPriority
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY
          /* pile of sort conditions here */
      ) AS "newPriority"
    FROM
      "items"
  ) AS tempTable
WHERE
  "items"."id" = "tempTable"."id"
;
```

I keep getting a syntax error "near FROM".

How can I correct the syntax here?

Comment: This is very hard to do in SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQLite** is not as flexible as other rdbms, it does not support even joins in an `update` statement.
What you can do instead is something like this:

```
update items
set priority = 1 + (
  select count(*) 
  from items i 
  where i.id < items.id
)
```

With this the condition is derived only by the `id`s. 
So the column `priority` will be filled with sequential numbers `1, 2, 3, ....`
If you can apply that *pile of sort conditions* in this manner, you will make the update work.
**Edit**.
Something like this maybe can do what you need, although I'm not sure about its efficiency:

```
UPDATE items
SET priority = (
  SELECT newPriority FROM (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY /* pile of sort conditions here */) AS newPriority
    FROM items
  ) AS tempTable
  WHERE tempTable.id = items.id
)
```

Comment: Hmmm... I tried this method earlier but ended up where all `priority` values were equal to the same thing.  I'll fiddle with it some more and see if I can get it to cooperate.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I've posted a different simpler question related to `UPDATE`, and the fact that I can't seem to get more than the top value to apply.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55997684/update-with-multiple-values-from-subquery  I'm guessing the answer here is also an SQLite limitation, but if you have any thoughts on it, I'd love your feedback!  Thanks.

Comment: I think my 2nd query works. See this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/br3kpcEU6DUbaaw334rCrz/0. The order condition is simple: `ORDER BY name`. If you can adjust your *pile of sort conditions here* you can make it work for your case.

Comment: Thanks, yes the second query worked out!  I ended up going that route.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the root answer to this specific question is that SQLite doesn't support `UPDATE ... FROM`.  Therefore, some alternative methods are needed.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Comment: Why link to *draft* documents and not the official version?

Comment: @Shawn Fixed, thanks.  It was just what I came across via Google... didn't see that it was a draft.