# UPDATE with multiple values from subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose I have a table, `items`, with an integer column named `priority`, which I'm trying to update from another table.  (This other table is a temporary table, where I've pre-calculated all of the appopriate `priority` values to be applied.)

```
UPDATE "items" SET "priority" = (
  SELECT "newPriority" FROM "newPriorities"
);
```

What ends up happening is that all entries in `items` have their `priority` set to the *first* value returned from the `newPriorities` sub-query.

How can I set `priority` to be different for each record?  To put it another way, how can I update `items` to have all of the correct `priority` values from the `newPriorities` table?

### Sample Data

#### `items`

```
id                                      priority  /* some other, unreleated columns */
2108f97e-e1ce-47bf-97fd-c20699d2aa27    0
fae2347c-8644-47ba-931f-3d3cf70d3565    1
bd5ed046-47fa-49d9-9b40-2aa920511cf2    3
1fc57417-93e1-4382-8246-c4f9d117a55a    4
2ab4afbc-aa56-45af-8509-a7d9377e689d    5
7407a3a5-d410-4190-81c8-54d672f22c8d    6
1b21b57e-e907-4c25-af00-94bbf941df63    7
```

#### `newPriorities`

```
id                                      newPriority
2108f97e-e1ce-47bf-97fd-c20699d2aa27    15
fae2347c-8644-47ba-931f-3d3cf70d3565    22
bd5ed046-47fa-49d9-9b40-2aa920511cf2    554
1fc57417-93e1-4382-8246-c4f9d117a55a    8
2ab4afbc-aa56-45af-8509-a7d9377e689d    3
7407a3a5-d410-4190-81c8-54d672f22c8d    6
1b21b57e-e907-4c25-af00-94bbf941df63    743
```

**Desired Result**: `newPriority` column values copied to `items`.

Comment: You need a key for a correlation clause.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, keys are available!  I've posted some sample data and a specific desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
UPDATE "items" as i
    SET "priority" = (SELECT "newPriority" 
                      FROM "newPriorities" np
                      WHERE np.id = i.id
                     );
```